# How do I use Angular UI Grid (native to AngularJS) in an Angular 8 project

Tags: datatables, angular8, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to use the Angular UI Grid in my Angular 8 project. Looking online i can't seem to find anywhere which tells me how to configure it properly.

I know that Angular UI grid is native to AngularJS. But is it possible to implement this into a TS project? I need the table in various different components.

Any help would be great!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ag-grid,mat-table,ngx-datatable instead of angular UI grid.